# How can I show a video in my view [.Net MAUI]

Tags: maui

Hi I am currently starting to work with .Net Maui for a project that I am starting I need  to   show a video in my view. How can I display a simple media player  and  show a local stored video. In the docs I didn´t find anything about that. I hope  anybody have a solution for  that

Comment: See discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2292) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6764). Unfortunately, there is no official solution yet. That first issue (#2292) will be updated when there is a solution available. In the meantime, you might be able to use the Xamarin `MediaElement` via [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.MauiCompat/2.0.1-preview1007).

Comment: Better: See [Proposal MediaElement](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/113) for current status. Implementation is currently blocked, waiting on android media streaming support (some Google code) to be useable from .Net 6 on Android.